# Cocos2d - how to scale two CCNodes with respect to each other

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, scale, ccnode

I have two CCNodes in Cocos2d that I want to dynamically scale in sync with each other.  Both CCNodes are background nodes.  Visually one CCNode, NodeA, is above the other CCNode, NodeB in the y direction.  But when I scale both nodes at the same time as in the code below:

**Edit #1 -**

Node B is part of a CCLayer, HUDLayer.  The HUDLayer doesn't scale but NodeB in the HUDLayer does scale.  So the code looks like

```
NodeA.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.0f);
NodeA.scale = scale;
HUDLayer.NodeB.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.0f);
HUDLayer.NodeB.scale = scale;

4)  Would NodeB being part of a CCLayer effect the Nodes scaled relative positions?
```

**End Edit #1**

**Edit #2**

```
 The contentSize of CCNode is (0,0).  How do I set the contentSize of CCNode manually?
```

**End Edit #2**

**Edit #3**

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234746/rotate-a-sprite-around-an-anchor-point) where one of the answers talks about setting a CCNode's relativeToAnchorPoint property to YES.  I can't find how to do this on Google.  Does anyone know how to set relativeToAnchorPoint?

**End Edit #3**

NodeA drops below NodeB in the y direction.  So this brings up a few questions:

```
1)  Are CCNodes scaled with respect to an anchorPoint?
2)  Why is NodeA dropping below NodeB in the y direction?
3)  How can two CCNodes be scaled with their relative positions remaining constant?
```

Comment: it's not so much the scaling happens in respect to the anchor point, but their position. So the anchor point at .5, 1 will have its top most point stay in the same position as it grows.

Comment: So is the trick that I need to find an anchorPoint for both Nodes so that they stay fixed relative to each other?

Comment: I don't know what the exact effect your looking for is, but yeah, basically. Keep in mind that the anchor point is relative to the contentSize of the object, and adding child nodes does not alter the contentSize. Only the texture, or manual setting affect the contentSize.

Comment: The CCLayer has a contentSize, but does a CCNode have a contentSize?

Comment: It has one, but by default it is (0,0), since there is no texture that would give it a size by default. As I've said, adding children does not change the node's size. You could give it a size manually however. If something has no size, then the anchor point setting really has no effect (the anchor point will always be at 0,0 of the node).

Comment: Right, that is what I have noticed is that the anchorPoint has no effect on the CCNode.  In fact the anchorPoint doesn't seem to have any effect on NodeB either.

Comment: Now if instead of nodes, they were sprites with textures (which sets a contentSize automatically), or if you were to set the contentSize for your nodes manually, the anchor point would then start having an effect.

Comment: I tried setting the contentSize as ccnode.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480.0f, 320.0f); but it didn't seem to cause the anchorPoint code to work with ccnode.anchorPoint = ccl(0.5f, 0.0f);.

Comment: How does one scale to the children in cocos2d?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. see 1 especially if they are not the same size
3. set their anchorpoint to 0.5,0 so they both align on the bottom when scaling

Comment: That still doesn't work.  Must be something else I am missing.  I added more information in Edit #1.  Btw I've got your book and its a great book.